# "Please insert CentOS disk 2 to continue" error on VMware

Tags: centos, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) on VMware, I download [CentOS-5.3-x86_64-bin-1of7.iso](http://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/5.3/isos/x86_64/). But in the middle of the installation I'm getting `Please insert CentOS disk 2 to continue`, here a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The name of the ISO file should be a hint, "1of7".  The download site that you link to has seven ISO files.

Comment: So I need to download all of them you think?

Comment: I don't know what's on them, but you need the second one for sure.

Comment: @Kusalananda: The OP should be downloading the DVD version for this purpose, which is all-in-one. The CD downloads are only for people who really do have CD-only drives. For installing a VM, you don’t need the broader compatibility that using ISO9660 media gets you.

Comment: @Plompy: Why do you believe you need CentOS 5.3, specifically? 5.11 is the last release of CentOS 5. For most purposes, the only differences between 5.3 and 5.11 are security updates and bug fixes. Functional changes are rare within a major release, and breakages rarer still. Functional breakages are restricted to major releases: CentOS 5 → 6 and 6 → 7. Staying on a particular CentOS point release is almost always due to a mistaken belief that upgrading will break something. The whole point of CentOS’s “stable” nature is that keeping up on security upgrades and such *doesn’t* break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only wonder why you're installing a system from 2009. The multiple CD distribution form was quite usual at those times, so small wonder it does ask for another CD. The first CD used to be the one for the installation boot-up and then the others kicked in in the process. In the link in your question, there's a magnet link to a DVD version. I'd rather go for this, as your VMWare may not be that far compatible historically. (It may, just my guess.) In case you just want to install CentOS and somehow drifted to 2009, go to their main page and take the simple route via a download section present on all such sites.

Comment: I have some test in this OS therefore I'm trying to dowloaded it to my pc, can you please add the link for better version? I need CentOS 5.3

Comment: @Plompy It's in the link you posted: https://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/5.3/isos/x86_64/ Choose this one: CentOS-5.3-x86_64-bin-DVD.torrent This is a torrent downloader. Depending on your client, double click it or open it if it doesn't open automatically. This is what you need: https://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/5.3/isos/x86_64/CentOS-5.3-x86_64-bin-DVD.torrent